# Why are inverse images much better behaved than forward images?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, and $A\subseteq X$, then we define the (forward) image of $A$ under $f$ as the set $f(A)=\{y\in B:(\exists x\in A)(y=f(x))\}$; similarly, if $B\subseteq Y$, then the inverse image of $B$ under $f$ is defined as $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in A:f(x)\in B\}$.

Despite the apparent duality between these two concepts, it is well known that inverse images are in general much better behaved than forward images. While unions are preserved under images (i.e. $f\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right)=\bigcup_if(A_i)$), the corresponding equation for intersections is false, and taking the forward image does not interact well with taking complements. By contrast, pretty much everything that you would hope that inverse images preserve *is* preserved.

(This phenomenon is not limited to set theory. For instance, if $\phi :G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, then $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Again, the corresponding statement for forward images is false.)

Is there a deeper explanation, say using category theory, for why inverse images are in general much better behaved than forward images?

Comment: (I’m not exactly sure which tags to use for this question. If anyone knows a tag that would fit, then feel free to edit my post.)

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the requirement that functions be single-valued, i.e. that if $x = y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ (single-valued inverses correspond to injective functions, but we usually allow non-injective functions, so there is no such requirement when looking at inverse images). And also functions are required to be defined on their domain, which means their inverse is surjective.

Comment: (So to summarize, the definition of a function is inherently asymmetric in its treatment of the domain and codomain).

Comment: Note also that taking inverse images is a 'closed' operation, in the sense that $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subseteq Y$, but not so with images: $f^{-1}(f(X)) \nsubseteq X$ in general.

Comment: Certainly not deep: To check $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ you just have to evaluate and verify $f(x)\in B$. To check $y\in f(B)$ you have to solve an equation $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @JairTaylor You do have $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$ though.  (These two inclusions would correspond to the counit and unit of the adjunction between inverse and direct image operations that's mentioned in Fernando Chu's answer.)

Comment: I don’t want to write this out in detail right now, but there is a clear and simple categorical reason: $f^{-1}$ has adjoints on both sides, but $f_*$ has only a right adjoint. Mappings with right adjoints always preserve the kind of categorical thing that unions are an example of called *colimits*, and mappings with left adjoints preserve *limits*, such as intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this should be an answers but it's more like another perspective. Considering the poset of subsets, the forward image is left adjoint to the preimage function. Similarly, the preimage function is a left adjoint to some kind of dual forward image (exercise). Hence, the preimage function is both a left adjoint and right adjoint, so it preserves colimits (unions) and limits (intersections).

The reason why I say this is not really an answer is because this is almost trivial, since if a function preserves intersections, then it must be a right adjoint; so this is kind of like a restatement, although I guess the forward image-preimage adjunction is kind of "essential".

Comment: It seems that you regard forward images and preimages as adjoint functors. Can you explain this in some more detail?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Sure, the poset of subsets can be seen as a category with a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ iff $X \subseteq Y$. When regarded as such you can see that the forward image and preimage are functors. Finally, you can just check any of the adjoint conditions and see that these two functors satisfy them.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation (not really using category theory, except maybe for the fact that the relevant isomorphism is natural, but still hopefully somewhat deep) is that the power set $\mathcal P(X)$ is a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ algebra under the operations of symmetric difference $\Delta$ as addition and intersection $\cap$ as multiplication.

Moreover, this algebra is naturally isomorphic to the algebra $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^X$ of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-valued functions on $X$, via the identification of a subset $A\subseteq X$ with its characteristic function $\chi_A$.

Then if $f\colon X\to Y$ is any function, it's immediately verifiable that $g\mapsto g\circ f $ is an algebra homomorphism from $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^Y$ to $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^X$ , preserving multiplicative and additive identity and addition and multiplication.

Since $\chi_A\circ f=\chi_{f^{-1}(A)}$, the aforementioned homomorphism, in combination with the isomorphism $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^X\cong \mathcal P(X)$, then gives many of the nice properties of the inverse image map.

##### remark

As Qiaochu Yuan points out, this does not tell the whole story, as it only gives us preservation of complements, finite unions and intersections, when in fact, the inverse image preserves arbitrary unions and intersections.

We can see why those must be preserved by observing that $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^X$ is also partially ordered by pointwise comparison as well (taking $0<1$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) , and this makes the aforementioned isomorphism with $\mathcal P(X)$ an order-isomorphism as well.  Since arbitrary unions and intersections are characterized as [joins and meets of arbitrary families of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice), and these are preserved in an order isomorphism, the fact that unions and intersections are preserved by the inverse image map follows from the corresponding fact that pointwise suprema and infima of families of functions under the aforementioned map $g\mapsto g\circ f$ are preserved.

Comment: Well, not all of them. You get that inverse image preserves finite unions and intersections but in fact it preserves arbitrary unions and intersections.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it is well known that inverse images are in general much better behaved than forward images.
> ...
> This phenomenon is not limited to set theory. For instance, if $\phi :G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, then $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Again, the corresponding statement for forward images is false.

I do not agree. In topology images usually behave much better than inverse images. Here are examples:

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map. If $K \subset X$ is compact / connected / pathwise connected, then so is $f(K)$. The corresponding statement for inverse images is false.

But also in many other cases images are well-behaved. Images of subgroups under group homomorphisms are subgroups, images of linear subspaces of vector spaces under linear maps are linear subspaces, etc.

By the way, in the topological setting positive results for inverse images are available *under additional assumptions* concerning spaces and maps. For example, inverse images of connected spaces with respect to continuous, open and so-called perfect maps are connected.

This shows that "nice behavior" of images or inverse image depends on the context.

And more important, "nice behavior" of something is not a priori clear, it always *needs to be proved*. In many cases such proofs are fairly trivial, but there is no fundamental principle which allows to expect nice behavior of inverse images.

That said, let me come to your main question dealing with functions $f : X \to Y$ between sets $X,Y$. In this case inverse images definitely behave better than images in the sense that they preserve intersections and set differences, which is not true for images.

This question received nice answers illuminating broader aspects, but I do not think they are necessary to understand the asymmetric behavior of images and inverse images in set theory.

As pointed out in the comments, it is no big and deep mystery, the simple reason is the inherent asymmetry in the concept of a function $f : X \to Y$. An element of $X$ is mapped to a single element of $Y$, but an element of $Y$ in general has more than one preimage in $X$ (unless $f$ is injective).

Let us look at the consequences of this trivial observation. By $\mathfrak P(S)$ we denote the power set of a set $S$.

Each function $f : X \to Y$ between sets $X, Y$ induces two functions between power sets

$$f :  \mathfrak P(X) \to \mathfrak P(Y), f(A) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in A \} ,$$
$$f^{-1} :  \mathfrak P(Y) \to \mathfrak P(X), f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in B \} .$$

Thus for the inverse image we have the simple characterization
$$x \in  f^{-1}(B) \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in B , \tag {1}$$
but there is no analogue for the image. It is not true that
$$y \in f(A) \Longleftrightarrow \emptyset \ne f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset A . \tag{2}$$
Actually $(2)$ is true for all $A \subset X$ if and only if $f$ is injective. However, $\Longleftarrow$ is always true.

Let us now recall the more or less trivial proof that $f^{-1}$ preserves intersctions. We have
$$x \in f^{-1}(\bigcap_\iota B_\iota) \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in \bigcap_\iota B_\iota \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in B_\iota \text{ for all } \iota \Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(B_\iota) \text{ for all } \iota \\ \Longleftrightarrow x \in \bigcap_\iota  f^{-1}(B_\iota)$$
The "trick" is to shift $f^{-1}$ from the RHS to the LHS and conversely. This does not work for $f$ because $(2)$ fails to be true unless $f$ is injective. We trivially always have $f(\bigcap_\iota A_\iota) \subset  \bigcap_\iota f(A_\iota)$, but the basic problem with the reverse inclusion for a non-injective $f$ is that $y \in \bigcap_\iota  f(A_\iota)$ means that for all $\iota$ we have $y = f(x_\iota)$ for some $x_\iota \in A_\iota$, but we cannot expect that there is a common $x \in \bigcap_\iota  A_\iota$ such that $y = f(x)$.